# Can I invoke the doGet method and retrieve information from a servlet?

Tags: java, servlets

I have a doubt with servlets and the `doGet` method. I'm sorry if this is a wrong question, hopefully somebody will help me with this.

I have a servlet, which I invoke using this code to execute something in it:

```
public static void sendBeingRequestFromSimulator(String param2, String message) throws Exception
   {
      HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
      GetMethod method = new GetMethod(SERVER_URL);

      NameValuePair[] parameterArray = new NameValuePair[3];
      parameterArray[0] = new NameValuePair("param1", "begin");
      parameterArray[1] = new NameValuePair("param2", param2);
      parameterArray[2] = new NameValuePair("msg", message);
      method.setQueryString(parameterArray);
      client.executeMethod(method);
}
```

That makes the servlet to execute certain code. Then the servlet will receive calls from other applications, and will store that information.

I would like to know, if it is possible to access that information stored on the servlet calling the doGet method, or in some other way.

Any help will be appreciated

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You could have the servlet output various data in its response based on a query string that you send in the request.

Comment: thanks @jahroy, now my question is, how can invoke the doGet method and get the information from the response? Sorry if this sounds silly, but I've been looking in the web and I can't figure this out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *now my question is, how can invoke the doGet method and get the information from the response?*

It's available by the `getResponseXxx()` methods on `HttpMethod` class. See also its [javadoc](http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/apidocs/org/apache/commons/httpclient/HttpMethod.html).

E.g.

```
// ...
client.executeMethod(method);
int status = method.getStatusCode();
Header[] headers = method.getResponseHeaders();
String body = method.getResponseBodyAsString();
```

---

**Unrelated** to the concrete problem. HTTP client 3.x is rather legacy. Consider moving to HTTP client 4.x.

Comment: Thanks @Balusc, your code helped a lot, I had to add the information in the doGet method doing something like this: response.setContentType("text/html");

                  PrintWriter out = null;
                  try
                  {
                     out = response.getWriter();
                     String messageToReturn =Shared.getMessageFromQueue();
                     out.println(ussdMessage);
                  } 

and it worked like a charm.

Comment: You're welcome. That's indeed one of the ways to return a response in the servlet. You however seem to return text/plain. Please don't abuse text/html content type for that, it's for `<html>` response like as generated by JSPs ;)

Comment: Yes, the idea is to put an xml there. Finally it is going pretty well. Thanks again man.

Answer (score 1):

I believe I've used the [URL](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/URL.html) class to achieve this in the past.

You can use its [openStream()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/URL.html#openStream%28%29) method to get an InputStream you can read.

The returned InputStream should represent the output written by the servlet.

Answer (score 0):

Typically in a web application, the data sent from clients will be stored in some sort of database, either an relational database system, a document based system like couchdb, etc.

You servlet methods should invoke service methods (which you write), which both save and load data as needed.

Comment: Thanks @hvgotcodes, but the intention of this is to create jUnit tests, and to validate the servlet behavior, then, I do not need nor want to store the information in the database. However, thanks for your response.